# How to add text to request body in RestSharp

Tags: .net, xml, restsharp

I'm trying to use RestSharp to consume a web service. So far everything's gone very well (cheers to John Sheehan and all contributors!) but I've run into a snag. Say I want to insert XML into the body of my RestRequest in its already serialized form (i.e., as a string). Is there an easy way to do this? It appears the .AddBody() function conducts serialization behinds the scenes, so my string is being turned into `<String />`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: A sample of my current code was requested. See below --

```
private T ExecuteRequest<T>(string resource,
                            RestSharp.Method httpMethod,
                            IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters = null,
                            string body = null) where T : new()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(this.BaseURL);
    RestRequest req = new RestRequest(resource, httpMethod);

    // Add all parameters (and body, if applicable) to the request
    req.AddParameter("api_key", this.APIKey);
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (Parameter p in parameters) req.AddParameter(p);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body)) req.AddBody(body); // <-- ISSUE HERE

    RestResponse<T> resp = client.Execute<T>(req);
    return resp.Data;
}
```

Comment: What does your current code look like? And where in it do you have the problem?

Comment: sorry, didn't see this until now. you probably want AddParameter() for that. if that's not what you want, post to the google group with an example of the body with params + xml that you're trying to achieve. http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Here is how to add plain xml string to the request body:

`req.AddParameter("text/xml", body, ParameterType.RequestBody)`;

Comment: +1 Likewise, to add plain JSON, it's req.AddParameter("text/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: Actually, for Json it should be (at least for Rails) : `req.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);` Thanks to Jean Hominal for the tip [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141174/c-sharp-adding-double-quotes-to-start-and-end-of-json-string-results-in-server-d/14141580#14141580)

Comment: How would I go abouts setting this to just a HTML encoded string? I.e.  a large get val=2&val2=3 etc.

Comment: I would think req.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: Is there possible to pipe stream to body stream?

Comment: This comes with a size restriction of 64 KB, which results in return status codes of 0 where the size of the body is greater than 64 KB.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of RestSharp, and this method signature is not available.

Answer (score 7):

To Add to @dmitreyg's answer and per @jrahhali's comment to his answer, in the current version, as of the time this is posted it is `v105.2.3`, the syntax is as follows:

```
request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    ContentType = "application/json", 
    Name = "JSONPAYLOAD", // not required 
    Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, 
    Value = jsonBody
});

request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { 
    ContentType = "text/xml", 
    Name = "XMLPAYLOAD", // not required 
    Type = ParameterType.RequestBody, 
    Value = xmlBody
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but what ever I set in the Name parameter is actually set as content-Type. So for both ContentType and Name, I used "application/json".

Comment: I tried this and got a null reference exception from within rest#.  Found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44281853/109736

Comment: @JasonCoder thanks for the comment. Was it the same version as well, v105.2.3? I've had mixed results with later versions is the reason I ask. It's now on 106 which may not operate the same.

Comment: @GibralterTop my results were with 106.6.9