# How to make GET with request body

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core, restsharp

How do I make a `GET` query with request body using `RestSharp` (I'm using RestSharp `v. 106.6.10` with `.NET Core 2.2`). I can do it using `WebClient`/`Postman` etc. no problem.

Here's the code failing with `{["A non-empty request body is required."]}`.

```
var client = new RestClient("BaseUri");
var request = new RestRequest("URL", Method.GET);
request.AddJsonBody(Body); 
client.Execute(request); // {["A non-empty request body is required."]}
```

This represents a [valid](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/9962) use case, pity if it's not supported.

**Update**: The motivation for having GET requests with body is to avail of get requests having complex parameters, which can't be nicely encoded into a query string. I know people serialize their jsons an put them into a querystrings but I'd rather put it into a request body, considering it's a permissible usage after all.

Comment: it might be technically permitted, but - it isn't exactly normal usage; it doesn't amaze me that some tools don't love it; but : have you tried with `HttpClient` ?

Comment: take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095692/how-to-add-text-to-request-body-in-restsharp

Comment: @IvMisticos - doesn't work, getting the same error.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've tried WebClient and didn't seem to like it neither, saying explicitly that GETs aren't allowed having bodies.

Comment: @MarcGravell ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type. is what I'm getting from WebClient.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience `AddJsonBody` is completely broken (had a multiple times when it wasn't serialize my model just pasting in Body something like MyProject.Models.MyModel or even left body empty). So I use following:

```
var client = new RestClient("BaseUri");
var request = new RestRequest("URL", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
string serializedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Body);
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", serializedBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
client.Execute(request);
```

**UPDATE** sorry i wasn't patient when reading you question. Answer is provided for `RestSharp` not `PostSharp`

Comment: Tried it as it, got: "StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"

Comment: After adding: request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); I start getting my original BadRequest.

Comment: Possibly your server not allowing calls without `Content-Length` specified. Try to add `request.AddHeader("Content-Length", $"{System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(serializedBody)}");`

Comment: It's not the length, it's Content-Type what it's unhappy about. My guess it RestSharp could well use WebClient/HttpClient in which case it's predefined to fail.

Comment: RestSharp seems correct - this is not about PostSharp. I've suggested an edit of the question - waiting for peer review.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using **reflection**, to trick **WebRequest** that it is legal to send a body with a GET request.

1.Create Model for body parameters,

```
public class SampleBodyModel
{
    public String name{ get; set; }
    public String password{ get; set; }
}
```

2. Initialize the request.

   ```
   SampleBodyModel sampleRequest = new SampleBodyModel
   {
         name= "name",
         password= "password"
   };

   //initialize the API call
   var request = WebRequest.Create("API_END_POINT");
   request.ContentType = "application/json";
   request.Method = "GET";
   var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;

   // ------- Add these two lines if your using JWT token -------
   myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
   myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "TOKEN");
   // -----------------------------------------------------------

   var type = myHttpWebRequest.GetType();
   var currentMethod = type.GetProperty("CurrentMethod", 
           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(myHttpWebRequest);
   var methodType = currentMethod.GetType();
   methodType.GetField("ContentBodyNotAllowed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(currentMethod, false);

   //Add the Request body
   using (var streamWriter = new 
         StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
   {

        streamWriter.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleRequest));
   }
   var response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
   var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

   var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
   var json = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

   responseStream.Close();
   response.Close();
   ```